# LEFT JOIN with WHERE in a first table's field OR second table's field

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, database-design

```
SELECT COALESCE(tb2.number_new, tb1.number_original) as number
FROM
tb1
LEFT JOIN tb2 ON tb2.id = tb1.id
WHERE 
tb1.number_original = <PARAM> OR tb2.number_new = <PARAM>
```

The above query generates a full table scan. How to optimize it?

EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tb1   | index | number_original| number_original| 5       | NULL | 11683843 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tb2   | ALL   | PRIMARY        | NULL           | NULL    | NULL |        2 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

The problem I need to solve is:

Given `tb1` is a table that has field `number_original`, I want to create table `tb2` to store a new value for this field, (wich I called `number_new`). I did it because I can't alter `number_original` value, and I didn't like to create field `number_new` on table `tb1` because it would be NULL in 95%+ of 11mi records.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help or not but... get rid of the or by using the same statement as the select `WHERE COALESCE(tb2.number_new, tb1.number_original) = <PARAM>` may be more efficient...  but... it will never search original_number if new_number is populated.... So the results will differ...

Comment: `WHERE` with `COALESCE` makes no difference, full table scan... :(

Comment: You have a contradiction, please fix it.  First you `SELECT` from `tb2`; then you "want to create tb2".  Which is it?  If you are doing a `CREATE TABLE`, let's see it and the `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(tb2.number_new, tb1.number_original) as number
FROM tb1 LEFT JOIN
     tb2
     ON tb2.id = tb1.id
WHERE  tb1.number_original = <PARAM> OR tb2.number_new = <PARAM>;
```

This is a complicated problem.  First, try two indexes `tb1(number_original, id)` and `tb2(number_new, id)`.

You might be able to rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT COALESCE(tb2.number_new, tb1.number_original) as number
FROM tb1 LEFT JOIN
     tb2 
     ON tb2.id = tb1.id
WHERE tb1.number_original = <PARAM>
UNION
SELECT COALESCE(tb2.number_new, tb1.number_original) as number
FROM tb1 LEFT JOIN
     tb2 
     ON tb2.id = tb1.id
WHERE tb2.number_new = <PARAM>;
```

Each subquery should use one of the indexes.  This does incur the overhead of `union` (with duplicate removal), but that might be better than a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

You need indexes for `tb1.number_original` and `tb2.number_new`, and probably also for `tb1.id` and `tb2.id`.  Then you need MySQL to take advantage of your indexes.  I don't know if it will.

In general, a DBMS will scan a table when no index answers the search arguments for the query.